# Mercurial: received spurious file revlog entry

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to Mercurial, and I'm receiving an error I can neither understand nor find a description of online. Can anyone help me? The error is "received spurious file revlog entry", and it occurs when I do the following:

1. clone a mercurial repository
2. create a new mercurial repository on bitbucket to house a copy of this repository
3. push the cloned repository to the new repository

The full message log appearing in the terminal is:

```
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets                                                                     
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
remote: received spurious file revlog entry
abort: push failed on remote
```

Thank you!

Comment: This implies that something on your own machine corrupted your clone. Two obvious possibilities include: failing hardware (bad disk and/or memory for instance), or attempting to store `.hg` repository in a Dropbox folder or similar (Dropbox will overwrite critical data whenever it thinks it knows better than Mercurial).